# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ItemModel::GetItemCategories()

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to retrieve option values for a drop down menu from a database and I'm currently receiving this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ItemModel::GetItemCategories()
>   in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Coursework2\Controller\ItemController.php on line
>   101

This is the code where I tried to add the values:

```
<?php
require './Controller/ItemController.php';
$itemController = new ItemController();

$title = "Add a new Item";

$content ="<form action='' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a new item</legend>
        <label for='name'>Name: </label>
        <input type='text' class='inputField' name='txtName' /><br/>

        <label for='type'>Category: </label>
        <select class='inputField' name='ddlCategory'>
            <option value='%'>All</option>"
            .$itemController->CreateOptionValues($itemController->GetItemCategories()).
        "</select><br/>

        <label for='place'>Place: </label>
        <input type='text' class='inputField' name='txtPlace' /><br/>

        <label for='date'>Date: </label>
        <input type='text' class='inputField' name='txtDate' /><br/>

        <label for='image'>Image: </label>
        <select class='inputField' name='ddlImage'></select></br>

        <label for='description'>Description: </label>
        <textarea cols='70' rows='12' name='txtDescription'></textarea></br>

        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </fieldset>
 </form>";

include './home2.php';

 ?>
```

And this is the ItemController class:

```
<?php

require ("Model/ItemModel.php");

/**
* Contains non-db related functions for the Item page
*/
class ItemController
{

    function CreateItemDropdownList()
    {
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
                    Please select a category: <select name = 'types' >
                    <option value = '%' >ALL</option>".$this->CreateOptionValues($itemModel->GetCategories())."
                    </select>
                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'  /></form>";

                return $result;
    }
    function CreateOptionValues(array $valueArray)
    {
        $result = "";

        foreach ($valueArray as $value) 
        {
            $result = $result . "<option value ='$value'>$value</option>";
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function CreateItemTables($categories)
    {
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        $itemArray = $itemModel->GetItemByCategory($categories);
        $result = "";

        // Generate an item table for each item entity in the array
        foreach ($itemArray as $key => $item) {
            $result = $result . "<table class = 'itemTable'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan='6' width = '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$item->image'/></th>
                                    <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
                                    <td>$item->name</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Category: </th>
                                    <td>$item->category</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Place: </th>
                                    <td>$item->place</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date: </th>
                                    <td>$item->date</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='2' >$item->description</td>
                                </tr>


                                </table>";
        }
        return $result;
    }


    function InsertItem(){}

    function UpdateItem($id){}

    function DeleteeItem($id){}

    function GetItemById($id){
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        return $itemModel->GetItemById($id);
    }

    function GetItemByCategory($category){
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        return $itemModel->GetItemByCategory($category);
    }

    function GetItemCategories(){
        $itemModel = new ItemModel();
        return $itemModel->GetItemCategories();
    }

}
?>
```

I may have included some unnecessary code but would rather be sure that you know exactly where everything's coming from. Thanks!

//edit
Adding ItemModel as requested. Thx!

```
<?php

require ("Entity/itementity.php");

//Contains database related code for the item page.
class ItemModel {

    //Get all items from the database and return them in an array.
    function GetCategories() {
        // require 'dbconnect.php';

        //Open connection and Select database.   
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login") or die(mysqli_error);
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT category FROM items") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $categories = array();

        //Get data from database.
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($categories, $row[0]);
        }

        //Close connection and return result.
        mysqli_close($con);
        return $categories;
    }

    //Get ItemEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.
    function GetItemByCategory($category) {

        //Open connection and Select database.     
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login") or die(mysqli_error);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category LIKE '$category'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $itemArray = array();

        //Get data from database.
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $name = $row[1];
            $category = $row[2];
            $place = $row[3];
            $date = $row[4];
            $description = $row[5];
            $image = $row[6];

            //Create item objects and store them in an array.
            $item = new ItemEntity(-1, $name, $category, $place, $date, $description, $image);
            array_push($itemArray, $item);
        }
        //Close connection and return result
        mysqli_close($con);
        return $itemArray;
    }

    function GetItemById($id)
    {
        //Open connection and Select database.     
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login") or die(mysqli_error);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        //Get data from database.
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $name = $row[1];
            $category = $row[2];
            $place = $row[3];
            $date = $row[4];
            $description = $row[5];
            $image = $row[6];

            //Create item object
            $item = new ItemEntity($id, $name, $category, $place, $date, $description, $image);
        }
     //Close connection and return result
        mysqli_close($con);
        return $item;
    }

    function InsertItem (ItemEntity $item)
    {
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO items (name, category, place, date, image, description) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", 
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->name),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->category),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->place),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->date),
            mysqli_real_escape_string("Coursework2/Images/" . $item->image),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->description));

        $this->PerformQuery($query);
    }

    function UpdateItem ($id, ItemEntity $item)
    {
        $query = sprintf("UPDATE items SET name = '%s', category = '%s', place = '%s', date = '%s', image = '%s', description = '%s' 
            WHERE id = $id",
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->name),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->category),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->place),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->date),
            mysqli_real_escape_string("Coursework2/Images/" . $item->image),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($item->description));

        $this->PerformQuery($query);
    }

    function DeleteItem ($id)
    {
        $query = "DELETE FROM items WHERE id = $id";
        $this->PerformQuery($query);
    }

    function PerformQuery ($query)
    {
        //Open connection and Select database.     
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login") or die(mysqli_error);

        //Define query
        $query = "";

        //Execute query and close connection
        mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        mysqli_close();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: where is your item model class??

Comment: It may be caused by this line : require ("Model/ItemModel.php");

Comment: also check to if GetItemCategories() exists

Comment: Post the content of `ItemModel.php`